# Intellij IDEA 10 with Android 2.3

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-2.3

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 10 preview and have updated the android SDK to look at 2.3 which appears to have broken IntelliJ's support of android (no devices in the target device dialogue).  **I'm aware that ADB has changed location and have updated my path to include both the tools and platform-tools directories**.  I know IDEA 10 is a preview and I'm aware of everything which that entails, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to get it working with the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get it to work:

1. created symlinks (I'm on a Mac, on Windows I guess you would just copy) from all the executables in platform-tools to tools.
2. went into my project's Facet settings, selected Android, and hit the Edit button. IDEA showed some error messages, but then allowed me to reselect the platform I had previously selected.
3. stopped and restarted IDEA
4. when I next tried to run my project, it did show me the running emulators. It points out that 2.3 emulators are not compatible, but it does work fine with all my emulators